# How to execute code on server-side every 100ms java EE way?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to have my code executed every short period of time, for example every 100ms (or even less).

I guess I can spawn a thread and add an infinite loop inside it, but I don't think this is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

```
final Timer timer  = new Timer();
final int   period = 100;
final int   delay  = 0;

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        log.debug("executing something");
    }

}, delay, period);
```